# TJpegImage: Internal bitmap not updated after applying JPEG compression

Tags: delphi, compression, jpeg

I want to convert a BMP to JPG, compress that JPG and the put back the compressed JPG into the original BMP. 
However, it won't assign the compressed image to the BMP. I always get the orignal image into the BMP.

The code is below. To see the compression I set CompressionQuality = 1. This will literary ruin the image.

```
function CompressBmp2RAM(InOutBMP: TBitmap): Integer;
VAR
   Stream: TMemoryStream;
   Jpg: TJPEGImage;
begin
 Jpg:= TJPEGImage.Create;
 Stream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
 TRY
   Jpg.Assign(InOutBMP);
   Jpg.CompressionQuality:= 1;  // highest compression, lowest quality 
   Jpg.Compress;
   Jpg.SaveToStream(Stream);
   //Stream.SaveToFile('c:\out.jpg'); <---- this gives the correct (heavily compressed) image
   Result:= tmpQStream.Size;
   InOutBMP.Assign(Jpg);
   //InOutBMP.SaveToFile('c:\out.bmp'); <---- this gives the uncompressed image
 FINALLY
   FreeAndNil(Stream);
   FreeAndNil(Jpg);
 END;
end;
```

I have found an work around, but I still want to know why *InOutBMP.Assign(Jpg)* in the code above won't work.

```
   ...
   Stream.Position:= 0;
   Jpg.LoadFromStream(Stream);
   InOutBMP.Assign(Jpg);
   ...
```

To me it seems to be a bug. The JPG is not aware that the data was recompressed, so the internal bitmap is never updated. There should be some kind of internal "DirtyData" (or "HasChanged") flag.

So, what is the official solution for this? 
Having the JPG to reload ITS OWN DATA from an external data source (stream) seems rather a hack/temporary bug fix.

PS: Jpg.DIBNeeded won't help.

Comment: Saving an image to JPEG usually does not change the uncompressed in-memory representation. Getting the JPEG image to see the actual compressed image requires decompressing it as you already have observed.

Comment: @Robert - thanks. ok, so what is the "official" solution? The one where I reload from stream? Or there is a dedicated method (similar to DIBNeeded) to do that?

Comment: I don't know if there is an "official solution". From my point of view the workaround you found is exactly what I would expect. There may be other ways to "simulate" a JPEG compression result. However I doubt that Delphi has them integrated.

Comment: You cannot assign a jpeg to a bitmap without decompressing it. Assigning a jpeg to a bmp always decompresses it (otherwise it won't be a bitmap). If you want to store the compressed image somewhere, you need to write it to a file or a block of memory. Both is easily done with TJPEGImage.WriteToSTream.

Comment: @dummzeuch "assigning a jpeg to a bmp ALWAYS decompresses it" - this contradicts what happens in reality (in my CompressBmp2RAM function). I assign there a jpg to a BMP after I compress the JPG heavily but I don't see the effect of the compression. So, assigning a jpg to a bmp does not ALWAYS decompresses the actual jpg image. The JPG image is correclty compressed (as we can see if we save the stream) but jpeg's internal bitmap got stuck to the "original" image. I thought DIBNeeded was supposed to fix that.

Comment: I think the jpg already has a dib (the original), so maybe that's why DIBNeeded doesn't work. Saving to stream and loading it again will guarantee to work with the compressed Jpeg data. But, TJpegImage also has the FreeBitmap method, which looks promising, but doesn't have a description in the online documentation. It sounds like it's the reverse of DIBNeeded, maybe you can give that a try too, to see if it gets rid of the Jpeg's internal bitmap representation. You may need to call JpegNeeded first, to prevent ending up with neither, if that is possible at all.

Comment: @GolezTrol - thanks. I will try that. but I just also want to comment that having the JPG to reload ITS OWN DATA from an *external* data source (stream) seems rather a hack/temporary bug fix. At least there should be a method called "RefreshInternalBitmap" (DIBNeeded does not work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just checked the code of TJpegImage, and the hypothesis I posted in the comments seems correct.

TJpegImage keeps an internal TBitmap for the representation. When you call `DIBNeeded`, this bitmap is created based on the Jpeg image data.

GetBitmap (the private function that does the legwork for DIBNeeded) will first check if the bitmap is already assigned, and won't repeat the process if it is. So just calling DIBNeeded will not work in your case, since you're basically guaranteed to have this cached bitmap already.

The `FreeBitmap` method will free the internal bitmap, after which calling DIBNeeded will create a new one again. So I think the sequence you need is:

```
Jpg.Compress; // Make sure the Jpeg compressed image data is up to date
Jpg.FreeBitmap; // Clear the internal cached bitmap
Jpg.DIBNeeded; // Optional, get a new bitmap. Will happen when you assign to TBitmap.
```

I also mentioned `JpegNeeded` before, but that will do a similar thing as `DIBNeeded`: check if there is data, if not, call `Compress`. So you need to call Compress, like you did, to force this compression.

PS: TBitmap (and file formats similar to bmp), don't really know this kind of compression, so by assigning it back to the bitmap, you will have reduced image *quality*, but not image *size*. Some bitmap formats, including PNG, do compress by using (amongst others) run length encoding (RLE), which means something like spending just four bytes for saying *"And now, 54 times a pixel of this color!"*. That kind of compression won't work really well on images with lots of jpeg artifacts (the grainy/blurry side effect of the compression), so a PNG version of the compressed Jpg might be larger than a PNG version of the original, even though the quality of the original is better as well. This is especially true for images with large areas of the same color, like screenshots and certain artwork.

Comment: "E2362 Cannot access protected symbol TJPEGImage.FreeBitmap" - which means that this is not the "official" solution to the problem. Borland had something different in its mind, but forgot to document it :)  I know, I could use a hack to access that protected method... But again... FreeBitmap it was not intended to be called.

Answer (score 1):

The internal TJPEGIMage.GetBitmap function only creates an internal bitmap based on the current jpeg image if no internal bitmap has been previously created.

```
Assign Image A. Do not use Canvas.
Assign Image B. Use Canvas and see Image B.
Assign Image C. Use Canvas and see Image B.
Assign Image D. Use Canvas and see Image B.
etc.
```

This is definitely a bug in TJPEGImage. I'm using XE7, so maybe this has been fixed by now.

My workaround to always get the correct JPEGImage.Canvas bitmap is to clear any existing internal bitmap before the assignment.

```
TJPEGImage = class(Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage)
public
  procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
end;

procedure TJPEGImage.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
begin
  FreeBitmap;
  inherited;
end;
```

The code above is helpful when using one TJPEGImage to handle a lot of different images. For only a few images, creating a new TJPEGImage for each image works.